# Cause for undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, glibc

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 which comes with gcc 5.4.0, g++ 5.4.0, and glibc 2.23.

The reason I'm running old versions is so that I can use linuxdeployqt to create an AppImage of my application. Ubuntu 16.04 is the latest Ubuntu version compatible with linuxdeployqt.

I'm currently just trying to build my application on the system (not using linuxdeployqt) and getting the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
```

Other questions like [OpenPose linking error on std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361134/openpose-linking-error-on-stdthread) say to simply install the newest version of gcc/g++ to fix the issue, however using an old version is the point in this case.

g++ 5.4.0 was released in 2015, how could it be incompatible with a C++ 11 feature?

Comment: "how could it be incompatible with a C++ 11 feature?" - I don't know if that is actually the error, but it is absolutely possible for a compiler released even years after a standard to not completely implement the standard.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling multi-threaded code with g++ the -pthread command line argument is required.